# Symfony form datetime to return unix timestamp

Tags: php, symfony

i want  to get the unix time using the symfony form

i tried with :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add(
            'source','text',array(
                'attr' => array('placeholder'=> 'z.B Hamburg',
                    'id'=> 'dirSource'),
                'label'=> false
            )
        )
        ->add('destination','text',array(
                'attr' => array('placeholder'=>'z.B Berlin',
                    'id'=> 'dirDirections'),
                'label'=> false
            )
        )
        ->add('time', 'datetime', array(
            'input'  => 'datetime',
            'data' => date_create(),
            'widget' => 'choice',
        ))
        ->add('Berechen','submit')
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

$url2 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Berlin&destination=Hamburg&mode=transit&departure_time=".$timee."&key=" . $key;
```

I want to send the unix timestamp value to the google map.

But it returns array....

in the twig

```
{{ time|date('U') }}
```

I also tried with ***strtotime*** but it returns error

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current time, use :

```
{{ "now"|date("U") }}
```

if `time` is a variable, your code is good except for the extra space before `date()` :

```
{{ time|date('U') }}
```

**Update** : following your clarifications, I think you want to use `input => "timestamp"` and not `"datetime"` in your form (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html)

Comment: nah i only want to pass unix timestamp from the user form for further process...

just wanted to see if i am passing the right unix timestamp value to my other methods..


btw i did tred with the above..

error Array to string conversion

Comment: Can you show us your User entity then, especially its "datetime" field ?

Comment: I made changes to the post

Comment: ->add('time', 'datetime', array(
                'input'  => 'timestamp',
                'data' => date_create(),
            ))

Unable to transform value for property path "[time]": Expected a numeric.

Comment: ->add('time', 'datetime', array(
                'input'  => 'timestamp',
                'data' => $now,
            ))
$now = (strtotime("now"));

it is still array.. when i need numeric